# Bounded partial derivatives imply continuity

Tags: analysis

As stated in my notes:

> **Remark:** Suppose $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$, $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and $p \in E$.  Also, suppose that $D_if$ exists in some neighborhood of $p$, say, $N(p, h)$ where $h>0$.  If all partial derivatives of $f$ are bounded, then $f$ is continuous on $E$.

I found a sketch of the proof [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2004;task=show_msg;msg=0766.0001).  I'm wondering if I can adapt this proof as follows:

$f(x_1+h_1,...,x_n+h_n)-f(x_1,...,x_n)=f(x_1+h_1,...,x_n+h_n)-f(x_1,x_2+h_2,...,x_n+h_n)-...-f(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}+h_{n-1},x_n+h_n)-f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n+h_n)-f(x_1,...,x_n)$

However, I'm not sure how to apply the contraction principle to finish off the proof.  Is there a more efficient way to prove the above remark?

Comment: University of South Florida?  It looks like you have a typo.  Do you mean $f(x_1 +h,\ldots,x_n +h)$ to begin with?  I don't think you can use the same $h$ for all the coordinates.  I should think using the triangle inequality and the Mean Value Theorem would work.  Begin by expressing $f(x_1 + h_1, \ldots,  x_n + h_n)-f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ as the sum of $n$ differences.  I didn't look at the link you provided.

Comment: I sort of provided it as $n$ differences...just with a fixed $h$.  That's where I'm confused.  I'm not sure I see how the MVT quickly applies.

Comment: You need $f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})$ to be close to $f(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{h}$ small enough, not just $\mathbf{h}$ with equal components.

Comment: Each of the $n$ differences can be bounded using the Mean Value Theorem, applied to $f$ along a line parallel to a coordinate axis and using a bound on a partial derivative.

Comment: I don't think the equation you entered is correct.  You need a finite telescoping series with as many plusses as minuses.

Comment: I looked at the link you provided and it looks correct.  They didn't explicitly mention the triangle inequality, which they used.  I'm not sure what "contraction principle" you're talking about.

Answer (score 7):

The proof is a combination of two facts:

1. A function of one real variable with a bounded derivative [is Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382820/79365).
2. Let $Q\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a cube aligned to coordinate axes. If  a function $f:Q\to\mathbb R$ is Lipschitz in each variable separately, then it is Lipschitz.

The proof of 2 involves a telescoping sum such as 
$$\begin{split}
f(x,y,z)-f(x',y',z')&= f(x,y,z)-f(x',y,z) \\ & + f(x',y,z)-f(x',y',z)\\&+f(x',y',z)-f(x',y',z')
\end{split}$$

Answer (score 0):

Can we use the increment theorem for the proof ?
$\delta z= f_{x}\delta x+f_{y}\delta y+\epsilon_{1}\delta x+\epsilon_{2}\delta y$ where $\epsilon_{1}$ and$\epsilon_{2}$ tends to $0$ as $\delta x,\delta y$ tends to $0$.
But $\delta z =f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)$.  Applying boundedness of partial derivatives $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ we get as $\lim f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)=f(x,y) $ as $\delta x,\delta y$ tends to $0$

Comment: no we cant as by using increment thm,basically u are assuming $f$ is differentiable;