# Show that a differential equation satisfies Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that if $$\frac{dx}{dt}=(3t^2+1)\cos^2(x)+(t^2-2t)\sin (2x)=f(t,x),$$ then $f(t,x)$ satisfied Lipschitz condition on the strip $S_{\alpha}=\{(t,x):|t|\le\alpha , |x|\le \infty , \alpha >0\}$.

---

Can I get some help for the above problem please.

Comment: For which variable Lipschitz condition will be satisfied? Also which order of Lipschitz condition do you need?

Comment: To show $|f(t,x_1) - f(t,x_2| < K |x_1 -x_2|$, first write the expression $|f(t,x_1) - f(t,x_2|$ completely, Put $|t| < \alpha$, apply trigonometric inequalities. For all sin ans cos terms with $(x_1 + x_2)$ take $< 1$. For sin terms with $(x_1 - x_2)$ take $< |(x_1 -x_2)|$. Do these and get your result. I do not want to write a long calcullation.

Comment: You may also try to show partial derivatives are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

To show that a function is Lipschitz on $S_\alpha$, it suffices to check that its partial derivatives are bounded on $S_\alpha$. See [Bounded partial derivatives imply continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351544/)

Here $f_x = -(3t^2+1)\sin 2x+2(t^2-2t)\cos 2x$ and $f_t=6t\cos^2x+(2t-2)\sin 2x$. 
Estimate the absolute value of each derivative using (a) triangle inequality; (b) the fact that sine and cosine are bounded by $1$; (c) the given bound $|t|\le \alpha$.

---

By the way, if you just want to apply the uniqueness/existence theorem, then only the Lipschitz  condition in $x$ is needed. For the $t$ variable, continuity suffices.