# Prove uniqueness of differential equation by finding the 'Lipschitz condition'

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Refer to Fitzpatrick's Advanced calculus Ex12.3 no. 9. The book tells that

If there exist a positive number $M$ such that $|g(x,y_1)-g(x,y_2)|\le M|y_1-y_2|$ for all $(x,y_1)$ and $(x,y_2)$ in the rectangle $[x_0-a,x_0+a]\times[y_0-b,y_0+b]$ where $g$ is continuous on the rectangle, given that $K$ is the bound of the function $g$ in the rectangle such that $aM<1$ and $aK\le b$, then there is a unique solution of differential equation $f'(x)=g(x,f(x))$ with boundary condition $f(x_0)=y_0$

Use the above theorem to find out $r$ such that the differential equation

$$f'(x)=\sin(xf(x))  \forall x\in(-r,r)$$ 
$$f(0)=1$$

has a unique solution.

I do not know how to check whether $g=\sin(xf)$ satisfies the above Lipschitz condition. I have heard that partial derivatives continuous implies $g$ satisfies the condition, but I don't want to use it to proof since I have not learnt it. So How to find the $r$ directly.

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin$ is Lipschitz (do you remember the proof about the derivative of $\sin$ ?).

Comment: @Tony Piccolo: Is $r=1$ correct? Also, partial derivatives continuous implies the derivatives are bounded and such M can be find (by MVT). However why http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468836/show-that-a-differential-equation-satisfies-lipschitz-condition/469297#469297 tells that one can check the boundedness of the derivatives instead of continuity to find out whether the function satisfies the Lipschitz condition?

Comment: See exercise 1.6 in this [pdf](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~jhateley/project/diffeq.pdf).

Comment: Thx a lot Tony!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why ... tells that one can check the boundedness of the derivatives instead of continuity to find out whether the function satisfies the Lipschitz condition?

Because boundedness is enough. But if you have continuity of $y$-derivative on a closed rectangle, that implies boundedness of $y$-derivative, and therefore the Lipschitz property of the function with respect to $y$.

Be careful with the Picard theorem, because it comes in different versions. The   [solution (ex 1.6)](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~jhateley/project/diffeq.pdf)   (provided by Tony Piccolo) uses a different version from what you stated in the question.  As you stated the theorem, it does not apply to very long intervals.

The crux of the matter is to choose $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the conditions of the theorem. We don't get these numbers from any formula: we have to choose them so that   the inequalities $aM<1$ and $aK\le b$ work. Since $M$ and $K$ may themselves depend on $a,b$, we may end up chasing our own tail.

But here, the derivative of   $\sin (xy)$ with respect to $y$ is bounded by $|x|$, which is *independent of $y$*. We can take $M$ to be the supremum of $|x|$ on the interval $[x_0-a,x_0+a]$, which is $|x_0|+a$. Also, the function $\sin (xy)$ itself is bounded by $1$ everywhere, so $K=1$.

So, choose $a$ so that $a(|x_0|+a)<1$. Instead of solving the quadratic equation, you can take $a=\frac12 \min(|x_0|^{-1},1)$. Then you apply the theorem repeatedly to expand the interval of existence... it's possible to cover the real line in this way.

But I'll have to say that this is a really laborious way to deal with this ODE. The proper way is to use the better form of the theorem, which does not require $aM<1$. See "optimization of the solution's  interval" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: But in this case, isn't that $x_0=0$? And than $a^2<1$ implies $|a|<1$. How can the interval be the whole real line?

Comment: @UnemChan Yes, you begin with $x_0=0$ and $|a|<1$. The theorem says the solution exists in this interval. It **does not** say that the solution stops outside of the interval. It's very possible that the solution goes on, but the theorem does not tell you about it. I outlined a typical way to make the theorem work harder and give you more information: apply it repeatedly, using different points $x_0$ from the interval on which you already know the solution exists. If you can cover the whole line  in this way, this means the solution exists on the whole line.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I suddenly think of a question: If I choose another $x_0$, I can find another interval such that the solution exist. However, how can I know that such solution match with the solution at another $x_0$?

Comment: @UnemChan If two solutions are defined on intervals with a common point, and they have the same value at that common point, then they agree everywhere. This follows from uniqueness of solution. Indeed, if they are not identically equal, then there is a point at which they diverge like train tracks, and then uniqueness fails at that point.

Comment: I mean that suppose there is a unique solution defined on $I_1$ if I choose $x_0=x_1$ and there is also a unique solution defined on $I_2$ if I choose $x_0=x_2$. I can know that the solutions agree at $I_1\cap I_2$ but may not at the other point.

Comment: @UnemChan Imagine going along the real axis, say left to right. Initially two solutions agree. Then you come to a point $a$ after which they become different. Apply the Picard theorem at that point. It will tell you there is a neighborhood of $a$ in which the solutions are still equal. A contradiction.

Comment: I see. Thx a lot