# Need to prove $f$ is continuous if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are all $C^{r-1}$-functions?

Tags: partial-derivative

I am reading "Basics of Manifolds" (in Japanese) by Yukio Matsumoto.

The following exercise is Exercise 4.2 on p.25 in this book.

> 4.2
> A function $f$ on an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is a $C^r$-function ($r\geq 1$) if and only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are $C^{r-1}$-functions.

The author's answer to this exercise is here:

> An $r$th order partial derivative of $f$ is obtained by partially differentiating one of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ $(r-1)$ times with respect to certain variables.
> Therefore if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are all $C^{r-1}$-functions, then any of $r$-th order partial derivatives of $f$ is continuous.
> So, $f$ is a $C^r$-function.
> The converse is obvious.

I think we need to prove $f$ is continuous if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are all $C^{r-1}$-functions.
If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are all $C^{r-1}$-functions, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are all continuous.
So, it is sufficient to prove $f$ is continuous if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are all continuous.
And I proved $f$ is continuous if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}$ are all continuous.
Am I right? (or is this fact obvious?)

Comment: You might want to edit your question because it seems you are asking a few different things in different paragraphs and title.

Comment: @Invisible Thank you very much for your comment. I edited the title.

Comment: Continuous gradient -> locally bounded gradient -> continuous

Comment: @Eric Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I found the following question in this site. : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2229771/384082

Comment: @Eric $U$ is an open set, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ may be unbounded even if it is continuous.

Comment: @Eric I am very sorry. You wrote "**locally** bounded gradient". Sorry.